# LED board connected to raspberry pi

Tags: display, arduino, output, breadboard

I've been searching for a little while for an LED light board for a while now that is easily compatible with the raspberry pi that I could use an arduino to my raspberry pi and then use my raspberry pi to display a simple scoreboard to a LED light board. I'm looking for one that can easily take input from a raspberry pi and a simple way to display information on the light board as such. Also I'm kinda going along the lines of wanting an LED board that looks like one from an arcade in the 80's for almost like a skee ball machine or a basketball shootout, arcade style, scoreboard. Does anyone have any good suggestions that would fit what I'm looking for. In not asking for opinions, just direction and what to search for or look for because I currently don't know what to do with the LED board.

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Raspberry Pi Stack Exchange! While not explicitly off-topic here, as you are *technically* asking for help with a LED board with the Raspberry Pi, this would fit much better and get better answers on [so].

Comment: @RPi+Awesomeness thank you, i wasn't really sure where to ask it, but thanks for the input

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you're looking for a [7-segment display](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seven-segment_display). I'm sure some place I've seen a nice module for controlling this with the Pi, but I can't find it now. The traditional approach is to use a breadboard. Each segment of the display is just an LED, so you can connect each one to a GPIO pin to power it. Then to generate the numbers you want it's simply a matter of turning the correct pins on and off. There's a good detailed explanation of how to do this [here](http://hackyourmind.org/articles/raspberry-pi-with-7-segment-display).

Comment: Glad to see we were able to answer this, but could you provide some of the process within your answer (at least the crucial parts)? It would help protect against link rot and would keep your answer useful for times to come, even if the link dies. Thanks!